# Generate multiple theme with single less file

Tags: javascript, css, less

In less file, I have two different color codes variables import, as of now I am hiding 1 import while generating other. I  would like to change the approach like having one import and passing my color less files dynamically to less file using Javascript.
[image: Less for multiple theme]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pass variables to less file using Javascript, there are two ways:

1. you could use javascript to inject a CSS stylesheet with updated CSS variables/properties or use javascript to directly set the CSS variables/properties.
2. serving LESS stylesheets and compiling them in the user's browser at runtime or recompiling them using `less.modifyVars`.Enables run-time modification of Less variables. When called with new values, the Less file is recompiled without reloading.

Simple basic usage:

```
        less.modifyVars({
          '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
          '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
        });
```

More details: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables

**EDIT:**

If you need to import your less file in js:

```
import '../less/style.less'
```

or, If you need to import your less file in parent less file:

```
@import "../less/style.less"
```

Use [Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature) for conditional-import

```
@bt-color-variation: light;

@import "color-variations/@{bt-color-variation}/global";
@import "color-variations/@{bt-color-variation}/variables";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Here less file not used in the browser side.Just generating css files locally and then deploy.  Using css variables also can be add to css files only. But I want to pass different  less color file to import dynamically with java script. Would like to know Is there possibilities. Thanks.

Comment: @ManjulaDhamodharan Why you need to do that? you could include child components in less file itself. Edited answer to how you can import less file in less or javascript.

Comment: I am having 2 different color codes variables in different less files and generating  each one with each theme color . How can I have both of them, only recent one of the import less color get compiled over writing the previous one.

Comment: @ManjulaDhamodharan so you need a conditional import based on color ?

Comment: Yes. Having all my less color files in loop, able to import all generate css files respectively.

Comment: @ManjulaDhamodharan Use Mixins. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @MebinJoe can you update that variable at runtime?